# Z-index doesn't works for Embed Code plugin

Tags: html, safari, z-index, always-on-top, html-object

I used Chrome & Safari browser to view live streaming.

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index:0;">
<object>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
    <embed id="SIPCtrl" type="application/xxxxx-plugin"  wmode="opaque"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

I also try to set like:

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index:0;">
<object>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
    <embed type="application/xxxxx-plugin" wmode="transparent"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

I have another div to show pop up message. I already set Z-index:1000 but it still doesn't show above the live streaming video (embed plugin). None of those two html could works.

HTML code: http://jsfiddle.net/8C2py/3/

Screenshot:  [image]

[Result]: Now is working in Chrome (add iframe), but no luck in Safari browser.

Can anyone tell me my mistake?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you also post the CSS and HTML of the other div? You might need to place the `object` in a div and set the `z-index` in this container instead of the `object`.

Comment: I already add the object div code. Thanks

Comment: `zIndex` may not work if position is `static` (which is the default).

Comment: may it works if position is absolute?

Answer (score 1):

Add `wmode="opaque"` to the      `object / embed`  tag parameters and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

pretty hard without seeing the entire code....try this
`<div style="position:relative; z-index:0;">`

on your container div. note: if you set z-index to negative on your container flash won't show up. doesn't look like you are using flash, but i'd avoid it anyways, just in case.

Comment: I have tried it and no luck.. I have updated my entire HTML code

Comment: can you put it up on js fiddle or post the url? without having the flash file to test, it's not the same

Comment: I have put it in my dropbox, this is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dkhd5jergbp3i0/sample_code.htm.

I used apple actX plugin with is similar with mine. When I tried it on Firefox it's works fine, but it doesn't work in Chrome & Safari. Thanks.

Comment: well the purpose of asking you to do it in jsfiddle was so we wouldn't have to set it up ourselves....moving along....you are missing the wmode="transparent" attribute/value on your second embed element. also, the div you are generating is being appended to the body element, not the div that you set to position:relative, so i put body{position:relative; z-index:0} in your head....works in chrome

Comment: I didn't set the wmode="transparent" attribute/value on my second embed element because it's works fine even I didn't set it, but it didn't work for the first embed element. I also have put body{position:relative; z-index:0} in my head, but still no luck. Did I miss anything?

Comment: which one is the live streaming vid? to the left or the right? it showed up above the youtube vid, which i assumed you wanted

Comment: I want the div element (appended to the body element) on top of everything (both video embed plugin & youtube). Thanks.

Comment: works for me, here's screenshot http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/i/delete/sample-code-ss.png  the reason it may not be working for you and is working for me is because xxxx.avi doesn't exist....which is another reason why i said to put it up on jsfiddle....it needs to be functional in order to test. the html document you sent me was just that...html doc, no avi. can't help you more without an avi

Comment: I have put my code here http://jsfiddle.net/8C2py/, also add screenshot above. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: looks like it works for me in chrome....just added wmode transparent to that same embed http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/8C2py/1/

Comment: Really strange it's look like my screenshot when I open your jsfiddle.. I tried to open it in my PC & laptop both the same, it doesn't works for me..

Comment: what operating system and version of chrome are you on currently

Comment: i looked at your fiddle....its not the same as the one i posted....adding the wmode to the second embed makes it work....at least from my perspective.

Comment: I used windows 7 & chrome Version 24.0.1312.57. But adding wmode to the second embed doesn't make any different, because as I mentioned previously --> "I didn't set the wmode="transparent" attribute/value on my second embed element because it's works fine even I didn't set it, but it didn't work for the first embed element" . Thanks

Comment: I have found the solution just add iframe inside the div like this http://jsfiddle.net/8C2py/3/. Now it's working in Chrome but no luck with Safari browser.. Thanks